# Use of block passed to Hash#fetch

Tags: ruby

[`Hash#fetch`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) returns the value in a hash for the given key.
It also accepts an optional block:

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h.fetch("a")                            #=> 100
h.fetch("z", "go fish")                 #=> "go fish"
h.fetch("z") { |el| "go fish, #{el}"}   #=> "go fish, z"
```

One would assume that a block will help us work on the value associated with given the key. However, the block seems to yield the key instead of the value (refer to the third call of `fetch` above).

What is the use of such implementation? I don't see any point in `key` being passed to the block as it is already known; it is the `value` that one is interested in, as is evident by call to `fetch`.

**UPDATE: This is invalid question, I misread the documentation. My apologies**

Comment: The block is evaluated when the hash has no value for such key. How can it pass a value?

Comment: ok, I guess I misread the documentation, I just read the part `if block is given...`

Comment: There are other methods that operate in an analogous way, such as [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-fetch) (and `merge!/update`) and [Array#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-fetch) when a block is provided (or a default argument for `fetch`) . `merge` defers to the block for the value of of a key that is present in both hashes being merged (and only then); `Array#fetch` invokes the block if an only an out-of-bounds index is referenced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The block is used for dealing with missing values - the value is not yielded because there isn't one.

You're supposed to use the key to return a suitable value (or raise an exception if appropriate)

Comment: If the key indeed had a value, what would you do in that case?  I am still not sure what purpose it serves

Comment: If the key is present in the hash, the block is not executed. `fetch` will just return the corresponding hash value.

Comment: @WandMaker You can either supply a default value, or a block to be executed and used instead. Sometimes the value cannot be known in advance, as is the case with your third example, it depends on the key, so it needs to be computed dynamically. That's what the block allows you do to.